# What does it mean for a random variable to be in a Borel set of R?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am revising probability theory and I can't seem to understand the concept of a random variable. It's a measurable function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, yet when we encounter probabilities of the form $\mathbb{P}(X \in A)$, we call this 'the probability that $X$ is in $A$' ($A$ being a Borel set). What does this mean? In what sense is $X$ 'in' $A$ as a function? This is very confusing...

In addition, when you see graphs of density functions in courses or on the internet, the x-axis always gives the probability variable $X$. I don't understand why this is, a random variable is a function, not a quantity, right? Do they mean the image? In that case is it sufficient for a density function to be defined only on the image of a random variable?

Comment: $P(X \in A)$ is shorthand for $P(\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A \})$ which is a bona fide subset of $\Omega$.

Comment: As for a graph of, say, the CDF, you're plotting $P(X \leq x)$ against $x$. For the PDF, you're essentially plotting $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{P(X \in [x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon])}{2\epsilon}$.

Comment: I know, but in what sense does this imply that $X$ is 'in' $A$? As in the sentence 'the probability that $X$ is in $A$'

Comment: It is the probability that you would see a value of $X$ which lies in the set $A$. For example, if $X$ has the discrete uniform distribution on $\{ 1,\dots,6 \}$ then $P(X \in \{ 1,2 \})$ is the probability to see a 1 or a 2 on a six sided die.

Comment: What makes this subject confusing is that $\Omega$ is almost always an abstract set, so you can't really visualize $\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A \}$. You can make things definite in my example with a d6 but leaning too heavily on this crutch will get in your way with even slightly more complicated scenarios.

Comment: Right, but the values of $X$ being in $A$ doesn't necessarily imply $A$ as a whole has to be contained in the image of $X$?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But that's always how preimages work: $f(f^{-1}(A))$ is a subset of $A$, sometimes a proper one. This just means that you can ask somewhat silly questions, such as the probability that my $X$ above is in, say, $(-\infty,0)$ (which is obviously zero, without needing to know anything about probability theory).

Comment: And in your example, $X$ takes the values of d6, but $\Omega$ would be the nth throw of the dice? And do they only plot the density function for $\Ima(X)$ to avoid these silly situations?

Comment: $\Omega$ is an abstract set. Trying to force it to be a concrete set is sometimes possible but basically never helpful.

Comment: And yeah, you would usually plot the density function excluding stuff that isn't in its support, unless its support is disconnected. But you *could* include whatever, the density in those other places would just be zero.

Comment: Thx, that's very helpful! I'll think about it and come back if I don't understand (and you'll indulge me)

Answer (score 2):

$X$ is a function $X\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, as you mentioned. By notational convention, we write
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X\in A\}
$$
for $\mathbb{P}\{\omega \in \Omega:X(\omega)\in A\}$, which is exactly
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X^{-1}(A)\}
$$
The reason is that we interpret that as *"the random variable is a function from the probability space, and what we consider is the probability that the 'output' of that function (what we can measure/observe) is in the set $A$."* That allows you to sort of completely forget the specifics of the set $\Omega$ itself: what matters is what you observe (the value the function takes, and where it lies.)